# SyntaxError: invalid syntax when trying to import networkx in Python3 (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, networkx, python-3.5

I use a DigitalOcean server running Ubuntu 16.04, and I have used networkx before with Python3. But when I tried to import networkx today, I received a syntax error.

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Oct  7 2020, 17:19:02) 
[GCC 5.4.0 --------] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import networkx as nx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/networkx/__init__.py", line 23
    f"{release.authors['Hagberg'][0]} <{release.authors['Hagberg'][1]}>\n"
                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also tried to uninstall and reinstall networkx, but I now get other syntax errors.

```
$ sudo pip3 uninstall networkx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

... on the attempt at install :

```
$ sudo pip3 install networkx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I researched online, and I saw that I needed to do updates, which I ran.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-dev
```

But these errors continue. Is there a dependency file I need to go in and manually change to Python3.5 ? I saw that somewhere. It feels like this is a stupid problem, and these are the kinds that always trip me up. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The errors you're getting from pip are not related to networkx. This suggests there's something deeper going wrong.  I have to admit, I have no good idea of what it could be.  I'd almost recommend starting over with a fresh python installation.

Comment: On re-examination, both of the errors seem to occur where there is a closing double quote.  Is there any chance these files might have gone through some editor that might have changed a double quote to a nicer looking double quote character that python wouldn't recognize?

Comment: O.K. I use this server as my main programming server. (I have made almost nonstop continual use of this server for programming for many years, but this is the first time I experience anything like this.) I will do as you say and try to uninstall python and reinstall. I shall report back what happens. Thank you so much.

Comment: No, no files have undergone any edits. I only suggested going into edit underlying files, bc there was such a recommendation here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235771/pip3-install-virtualenv-failed

I also created a test script, which solely imported networkx, but it triggered similar errors upon python3 execution from bash.

Answer (score 0):

I had to uninstall networkx and reinstall the prior version. That solved the issue.

```
$ sudo pip3 uninstall networkx
$ sudo pip3 install networkx==2.4
```

I was then able to run python3 and import networkx.
The bug was apparently from the current version of networkx (2.5). (I found this solution after I attempted a python uninstall/install, which crashed my server, and I was forced to restore to a prior back-up.) Don't ask me why this happened.